# Comparing more nested dictionaries (save time)

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity, nested-loops

I need an advice how to compare unknow number of nested dictionaries to have as low as possible time consumption.

So here is the example:

I have a data from house rental agencies. One house can be in more of these agencies. There are some information about each of these houses.

**1. Country**

**2. Date**

**3. Another information such as number of rooms etc.**

This data is stored this way:

```
DictionaryOnFirstLevel: key = Country, value = DictionaryOnSecondLevel
DictionaryOnSecondLevel: key = Date, value = instance of class House including price, Country, Date etc.
```

So, the thing I want is to find the same houses (the same two houses are not the same objects) and compare their prices and another data.

Since I know a country and a date I don't have to compare each house to each house - I don't have to compare object from Ireland to object from Turkey and the same problem is the dates - I don't have to compare objects with different dates.

```
for date in first_agency.house_dict['Ireland']:
    for h1 in first_agency.house_dict['Ireland'][date]:
        if second_agency.house_dict['Ireland'].has_key(date): # to save some time
            for h2 in second_agency.house_dict['Ireland'][date]:
                if h1.equals(h2): # method equals do some approximative comparison of names of houses and other attributes
                     #do some calculations and stuff
```

This code above is only for 2 agencies (1st and 2nd) and Country 'Ireland'. I get only those dates which are in the 1st agency in 'Ireland' key so I don't have to work with another dates because there is no chance that they would be worth.

So could you help me to improve my code so I can compare all agencies?

Comment: You do know your example isnt valid python code?

Comment: @muddyfish Why do you think that? Maybe I did some typo but I can't find it...

Comment: You have a variable `1st`. No variables can start with a number.

Comment: @muddyfish Objects are compared if and only if they have the same Country and Date.

Comment: @muddyfish Ok, I'm sorry this is just an example, I will correct that right now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the approach of many nested if + for loops is a bad approach since you repeat a bunch of code and it's very hard to test.

You might be better of breaking this into several functions

```
def get_all_duplicate_houses_on_date(date):
    """return a list of duplicate house lists (list within list)"""
    houses = get_all_houses_on_date(date)
    all_duplicates = []
    for house in houses:
         all_duplicate_lists.append(get_duplicates(house, houses)
    return all_duplicates

def get_duplicates(house, houselist):
    """return all duplicates of house in houselist"""
    duplicates = []
    for other_house in houselist:
        duplicates.append(other_house) if house.equal(other_house)
    return duplicates

def get_all_houses_on_date(date):
    """return all houses in every country on a given date"""
    all_houses = []
    for country in all_counties:
        all_houses.extend(get_all_houses_from_country(country, date))
    return [h for h in all_houses 

def get_all_houses_from_country_on_date(country, date):
    """returns all houses from all agencies in a given country
       and on a given date"""
    country_houses = []
    for agency in all_agencies:
        all_houses.extend(get_agency_houses_in_country(agency, country, date)
    return country_houses

def get_agency_houses_in_country_on_date(agency, country, date):
    """returns all houses from the given agency in a given country
       on a given date. Or return an empty list"""
    return agency.get(country, {}).get(date, [])
```

Now this is totally hacked together and I haven't verified there aren't any major flaws here, but the point is not the detail of the code; the point is that you create several, *testable* functions which each perform a unique task. Once you have a list of duplicates, you can do whatever you want with then, but that should be another function altogether.

In terms of optimization, it's probably much easier to try and optimize any one of the above functions individually. Looks like my naiive implementation above is like an O(n^n) time expense; not very good. My best guess is that you could probably get this down to O(n^2) but it may take some creativity.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try it. According to your last section - I think that time complexity is not the point here because there is a few houses with the same date and country so it should concern on filter them using this information. There is sometimes big difference between O(n^n) and O(n^n) in my opinion if you know what I mean. The number of house with the same country and date is such small that it could be practically considered as a constant. This is what I think, it could be wrong.